# What is the technology behind PhoneGap Build?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cordova, appmobi

As part of curiosity , what technology is used by platforms like AppYet , AppMobi and PhoneGap Build to comile app source code into .apk and .app format in the cloud.?

I have not been able to find any links that point to the technological setup and tools that being used on the server side for building code over the cloud.
Please point me to appropriate knowledge resources, Thank Yur

Comment: .apk extension is a simple .zip

Answer (score 0):

The real power behind Phonegap is that it enables you to build to different plataforms without any IDE, directly from the CLI.

Once a project is correctly configured, you can just type:

```
$ phonegap build ios
$ phonegap build android
$ phonegap build wp8
```

and Phonegap builds your app for iOS, Android and WP8

The syntax is identical when you build your application remotely using PhoneGap build

```
$ phonegap remote build ios
$ phonegap remote build ios
$ phonegap remote build ios
```

So, a wild guess would be that PhoneGap build is just a grid of nodejs servers running PhoneGap and a custom interface to receive project packages and serve the compiled apps